# Why does give ChatGPT exactly the same response to the prompt "ein hund kam in die küche"

Tags: chatgpt, prompt-design

I have never encountered this before, but ChatGPT (with GPT-4) behaves as I would have set its temperature to zero -- but I didn't. I just entered the following prompt **"ein hund kam in die küche"** (*"A dog came into the kitchen."*) and ChatGPT has answered more than 20 times word by word, token by token, letter by letter exactly the same:

**"Okay, was möchten Sie wissen oder besprechen, das mit dem Hund in der Küche zu tun hat?"**

(*"Okay, what would you like to know or discuss that has to do with the dog in the kitchen?"*)

From my point of view this is reproducible, inside a chat by clicking "Regenerate" or in new chats.

How can it be that there is not the slightest variation in this completion?

When I enter "ein hund kam in die", the completions vary:

"Es scheint, dass Ihr Satz unvollständig ist. Könnten Sie bitte den Satz vervollständigen, damit ich Ihnen besser helfen kann?"

"Es scheint, dass Ihre Nachricht abgeschnitten wurde. Könnten Sie bitte den vollständigen Satz oder die Frage formulieren?"

"Es sieht so aus, als wäre Ihre Nachricht unvollständig. Könnten Sie bitte mehr Kontext oder Informationen geben?"

Adding " und" finally helps him out: "ein hund kam in die küche und" is answered by "stahl ein Stück Fleisch vom Tisch." (*"stole a piece of meat from the table"*)

Comment: Have you found an official source saying that ChatGPT / GPT-4 was trained to handle prompts in languages other than English?

Comment: @Wicket  [ChatGPT Beyond English: Towards a Comprehensive Evaluation of Large Language Models in Multilingual Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.05613.pdf)